# Handling API Pagination, using a 'next.link" object

Tags: python, api, pagination, python-requests

I am using the `odata.nextLink` found at the bottom of certain requests to handle pagination. Per documentation, this key(odata.nextLink) would have a value ie a new url to make a request to. Here is my code , note there are over 1k pages. (ie "odata.nextLink" to follow and keep making requests) to get all the data. I am new to this and was wondering if my approach below was the correct **with the goal that it will not put too much stress on the API?**.. as you can see it makes a new requests for every odata.nextLink.**  The documentation said nothing about param arguments, it just said to get all the data use odata.nextLink. It comes down to less than 100 requests per 100 seconds, which I referenced as a baseline for google so it seems ok? Would appreciate a second opinion or code to somehow make it less of a strain on the source API.

```
def write_to_json_from_request(obj,buckt,path):



for key, value in obj.items():

    response =  requests.get('http://testapi.com/odata/' + value )
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Success!')
    elif response.status_code == 404:
        print('Not Found.')
    else:
        print('No luck')

    data = response.json() 


    inmemory = io.BytesIO() 


    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=inmemory, mode='wb') as fh:
                with io.TextIOWrapper(fh, encoding='utf-8',errors='replace') as wrapper:
                    wrapper.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False,indent=2))

    inmemory.seek(0)

    #Load file to S3 Bucket, and specific object , specify filename 
    cv.s3_resource.Object(s3bucket, s3path + str(key) + '_' + str(time.strftime("%Y%0m%0d_%H%M%S")) + '.json.gz').upload_fileobj(inmemory) 

    #close the stream   
    inmemory.close()

    for i in range(100000000):

        if data.get("odata.nextLink") != None:
            response = requests.get(data.get("odata.nextLink"))
            print(data.get("odata.nextLink"))
            # pagination_num = pagination_num + 1
            data = response.json()
            inmemory = io.BytesIO() 

            with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=inmemory, mode='wb') as fh: 
                        with io.TextIOWrapper(fh, encoding='utf-8',errors='replace') as wrapper:
                        # Writing into stream as json object
                            wrapper.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False,indent=2))

            # Set file's current position to 0    
            inmemory.seek(0)

            #Load file to S3 Bucket, and specific object , specify filename 
            cv.s3_resource.Object(s3bucket, s3path + str(key) + '_' + 'pagination' + '_' + str(time.strftime("%Y%0m%0d_%H%M%S")) + '.json.gz').upload_fileobj(inmemory) 

            #close the stream   
            inmemory.close()
```